# Keep only one header while merging multiple files

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy all the files from the specific folder and paste into one file. Macro is copying header from each file. I want header to be copied from first file only.

```vb
Sub MergeFiles()

'Declare variables
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim folderPath As String
Dim fileName As String

'Set the folder path where the files are located
folderPath = "C:\ExcelFiles\"

'Create a new workbook to store the combined data
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

'Loop through each file in the folder
fileName = Dir(folderPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While fileName <> ""
    'Open the file
    Workbooks.Open (folderPath & fileName)
    'Copy the data from the file
    Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Copy
    'Paste the data into the master sheet
    ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Close the file
    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    'Get the next file
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

'Save the master file
wb.SaveAs "C:\ExcelFiles\MasterFile.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: The `A1` is deciding what line to start copying from `Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Copy`

Comment: I want header from 1st file only for rest of the file want to copy from 2nd line

Comment: Yes, understood. I was merely telling you which bit you needed to change in order to achieve that. I've since supplied an answer that should do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some room for improvement here, such as finding the bottom of the table instead of assuming 10,000 rows is enough but - ignoring that - you could:

Add this with your declarations:

```
Dim firstfile As Boolean
firstfile = True
```

and then change your loop like so:

```
Do While Filename <> ""
    'Open the file
    Workbooks.Open (folderPath & Filename)

    
    If firstfile Then
        'Copy all the data from the file
        Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z10000").Copy
    Else
        'Copy from 2nd row, the data from the file
        Workbooks(Filename).Sheets(1).Range("A2:Z10000").Copy
    End If
    
    'Paste the data into the master sheet
    ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Close the file
    Workbooks(Filename).Close
    'Get the next file
    Filename = Dir()
    firstfile = False
Loop
```